# HTML: How to attach border image to a div

Tags: html, border

I need a shadow box border for my content div. Currently I am using the following code in the css to achieve this.

```
border-radius: 2px;
-moz-border-radius: 2px;
-webkit-border-radius: 2px;
-webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, .496094) 0px 1px 10px;
-moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, .496094)
```

But this only works fine with Google Chrome. The shadow box is not applied in other browsers. So I need to know how to use a border image to get repeated with div. Also tell me appropriate size of the image to be used... Thanks...

Comment: `.496094` for opacity? Seriously? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it only works in Chrome is because that's the only browser you gave any values to. For the Firefox rules, you left out `0px 1px 10px`
Also, you should order them properly and include the non-vendor specific property, as well to make it future proof. See here - http://css-tricks.com/ordering-css3-properties/
To get the shadow in IE without any images, check out http://css3pie.com.